# Cesium: Entity (point) is not shown in 3D mode?

Tags: cesiumjs

I've added an entity:

```
var debris = cesiumViewer.entities.add({
  position : { 
    value : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-75.59777, 40.03883, 1000) ,
    referenceFrame : Cesium.ReferenceFrame.FIXED 
  },
  point : {
    color : Cesium.Color.YELLOW,
    pixelSize : 6
  }
});
```

The point is shown in 2D and Columbus mode, but hidden in 3D mode. Also, in Columbus mode it looks like the altitude iz 0.

Added also `cesiumViewer.scene.globe.depthTestAgainstTerrain = true;`

Where is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

```
  var debris = cesiumViewer.entities.add({
    position : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-75.59777, 40.03883, 700000),
    point : {
      color : Cesium.Color.YELLOW,
      pixelSize : 10
    }
  });
```